# How to plot a table object in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Code :

```
library(plyr)
library(datasets)
data("iris")

iris$Sepal.Length

size <- c()
for (s in iris$Sepal.Length){
  if (s < 5.8){
    size <- c(size, "SMALL")
  } else if(s >= 5.8){
    size <- c(size, "LARGE")
  }
}
iris$Size <- size
plot(table(iris$Species, iris$Size))
```

plot :

[image: image1]

---

I'm wondering how to plot this kind of thing in ggplot.

I have this (which is dependent on the previous code):

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(iris$Species, iris$Size)), 
       aes(x=Var1, y=Freq, fill=Var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill") + 
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=15),
        text = element_text(size=15)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("S1", "S2", "S3")) + 
  labs(y = "Percentage") + 
  labs(x = "") + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text()) + 
  ggtitle("Something about iris stuff") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Size")
```

[image: image1]

Which communicates similar information, but it's not the same.

So - how can I make the a table in ggplot like that of `plot(table(a, b))`. I don't want it to be stylistically exactly the same ( or I'd just use base ), but I like the way that the proportions are displayed in that table more than the bars that I have with gg

**The ability to be able to pass a table object is useful here as I'm generating the plots with base within a for loop**

## Edit - code which plots within a loop

*I shall edit this post when it's finished so that it's cleaner, I didn't want to
delete stuff that people might currently be looking at referencing*

Here's some code that plots within a loop, by plotting a table object. I'm not
sure how I would go about doing this in ggplot.

```
rm(list=ls())

library(plyr)
library(datasets)
data("iris")
set.seed(1234)

iris$Sep.Size <- c("SMALL", "LARGE")[(iris$Sepal.Length >= 5.8) + 1]
# create an additional categorical variable, purely for the sake of plotting it
iris$Data.2 <- cut(
  rnorm(150, 10, 2), 
  c(-Inf, 8, 10, 11, Inf),
  labels = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  include.lowest = TRUE)


iris.2 <- data.frame(data = iris$Data.2, sepsize = iris$Sep.Size, species = iris$Species)

# plotting tables using a loop - one of them will be nonsense, but the others are usable. 
for ( i in 1:dim(iris.2)[2]){
  t = table(iris.2$species, iris.2[,i])
  plot(t)
}
```

There are 3 plots created as a result of this

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you don't like about the 2nd plot - the absence of spacing?

Comment: I wanted to be able to plot table objects within a for loop. I thought this example was clear, but thinking about it now perhaps I should have included an example of such plotting. Sorry about that. I'll edit this later to include that

Comment: Tip: `size <- c("SMALL", "LARGE")[(iris$Sepal.Length >= 5.8) + 1L]`. A one-liner. No loops at all. R is a **vectorized** language.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks, how would that be extended to 3 or 4 levels though?

Comment: You can use `findInterval` or `cut`. In the latter case, you would set the `labels` to the character values you want. In the former, use the return value of `findInterval` to index a vector of values for `size`. See the edit to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following is not exactly what you are asking for but it solves your problem in a somewhat natural way.

It uses package `dplyr` to pipe the dataset to `as.data.frame`. And to `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)

data("iris")

size <- c("SMALL", "LARGE")[(iris$Sepal.Length >= 5.8) + 1L]
tbl <- table(iris[5:6])

tbl %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Freq, fill = Size)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill")
```

On the downside, you have to load an extra package.

As for the new vector `size`, it can be created using

**`findInterval`.**

```
Size_Values <- c("SMALL", "LARGE")
i <- findInterval(iris$Sepal.Length, c(0, 5.8, Inf))
size2 <- Size_Values[i]

identical(size, size2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**`cut`.**

In this case the output is an object of class `"factor"`.

```
size3 <- cut(iris$Sepal.Length, c(0, 5.8, Inf), labels = Size_Values,
    include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)

identical(size, as.character(size3))
#[1] TRUE
```

**EDIT.**

In order to address the change in the question, with new data, the following code plots two tables in the same graphic window. The dataset `iris.2` is created in the question in a reproducible manner, setting the pseudo RNG seed prior to calling one of the built-in PRNG functions.

```
# plotting tables using a loop
# the columns to plot are determined by 
# these 2 instructions
ref <- "species"
others <- names(iris.2)[names(iris.2) != ref]

old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
for(i in others){
  tbl <- table(iris.2[[ref]], iris.2[[i]])
  plot(tbl)
}
par(old_par)
```

Comment: I've added an example with a for loop, I'm unsure how that would be done ( or if it can be ) with ggplot

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using the `ggmosaic` package?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)
library(datasets)

size <- c("SMALL", "LARGE")[(iris$Sepal.Length >= 5.8) + 1L]

ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Size, Species), fill = Size), na.rm = TRUE)
```

and you can then format the chart as you'd like.

**EDIT:**

To address the loop requested (based on the `iris.2` dataframe created in the original question and using code from Rui Barradas above) you can use:

```
ref <- "species"
others <- names(iris.2)[names(iris.2) != ref]

for (i in others){
  tmp <- iris.2[, c(ref, i)]
  p <- ggplot(data = tmp) + 
         geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(species, !!ensym(i)), fill = !!ensym(i)), na.rm = TRUE)
  print(p)  
}
```

This should create a different mosaic `ggplot` for each variable against `species`. Of course, you can format the charts accordingly inside the loop, or even save each plot in a list and then plot them on the same page if required.

Comment: Great! Didn't know about package `ggmosaic`.

Comment: Thanks, how would this be done within a for loop though ? I've edited the post to make this part clearer (hopefully)

Comment: I'll add the code for a loop later today. The idea is simply to use only the relevant variables in the darafrane used for plotting.